# Cleric without spellcasting

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, cleric

There are variants for paladins and rangers that allows them to trade spellcasting ability for other class features. It described in the Complete Warrior book on page 13. I'd like to play a cleric character that mess with no spellcasting. So I'm searching for something similar for the cleric class. Some way to sell spellcasting for other features.

Alternate class features or race based substitution is good choice. I'm not aware if choices are limited with this two.

What are my options?

Comment: So you just want turn or rebuke undead and maybe domain granted powers and the aura that comes from being a cleric? Is reskinning an option or must the character sheet say *cleric*?

Comment: @HeyICanChan: You are right. I want 1-level dip in cleric. Good Fort and Will saves, two bonus feats (from certain domains). Cleric is the best class for feat budget (two real feats and 1st level). But 1st level spellcasting is useless

Comment: @ayvango So, you're specifically looking for an ACF (alternate class feature) or racial substitution level that trades cleric spellcasting for something else?

Comment: @Miniman yes. Should I say it clearly in the question?

Comment: @ayvango Probably best, to avoid close votes and answers saying "Just be a Paladin!" and the like.

Comment: You know that spellcasting grants the character a spell list, and that enables the character to use all the cleric wands and staffs, right? There's nothing bad about cleric spellcasting when used with spell trigger magic items. (I mean, unless the character can already consistently hit DC 20 Use Magic Device skill checks.)

Comment: Are you willing to consider other divine classes like Warpriest, or are you really dead set on what 1 level of cleric provides? It might help if the question included what you are building off of to see if there's an acceptable alternative for your needs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**There is no official cleric variant that does not have casting**

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017050930/http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=7908) is a complete (as far as I can tell) list of alternative class features from official 3.5 books, and [here's](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=9028.0) one for Dragon magazine's 3.5 stuff. None of the cleric examples feature a removal or swap away of casting.

Personally, I would look at the first level, even if you have only Wisdom 10, as the ability to use cleric wands without needing to roll a Use Magic Device check. In addition, there's always some nice tricks you can get out of cleric orisons and 1st-level spells, such as the *no light* orison (BoVD), which is one of the only sources of true, complete darkness in the game. *Cure minor wounds* is always useful to have on hand for stabilizing if things go south, as well. In addition, the cloistered cleric archetype gets *identify* without needing a material component, which is amazingly useful.

Comment: I have created *several* characters with Wisdom 10 *or less* who nonetheless take a level of cleric. Also, cloistered clerics get *identify* as a 1st-level spell and don’t need the material component for it.

Comment: Good point. Edited it in.